# NoSuchSessionException in Selenide with TestContainers

Tags: java, selenide

I have test which fails every single time, when runs together with other tests in same class. When I run only this test - test is green.

Execption is:

```
NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
```

Stack trace is:

```
Timeout: 5 s.
Caused by: NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebElementSource.createElementNotFoundError(WebElementSource.java:37)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.ElementFinder.createElementNotFoundError(ElementFinder.java:100)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebElementSource.checkCondition(WebElementSource.java:65)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Should.should(Should.java:35)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Should.execute(Should.java:29)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Should.execute(Should.java:12)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.commands.Commands.execute(Commands.java:144)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.dispatchAndRetry(SelenideElementProxy.java:99)
    at com.codeborne.selenide.impl.SelenideElementProxy.invoke(SelenideElementProxy.java:65)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy197.should(Unknown Source)
    at eu.yals.test.selenide.page.info.AppInfoViewUITest.pageHasNonEmptyVersionLine(AppInfoViewUITest.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    ...
```

Source code is here: [https://gist.github.com/kyberorg/dafc9e317260f33f4cf75b6e178e0d3b](https://gist.github.com/kyberorg/dafc9e317260f33f4cf75b6e178e0d3b/)

Red test: `pageHasNonEmptyVersionLine`

I debugged and found, that this error occurs already at first line of method `SelenideElementProxy.invoke()` line 56.